# SQL Invalid Identifier when trying to run simple script

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to run the following Oracle SQL script which should create a new column, `TEMPLATE`, and populate it with some base values, but I'm getting an error.

```
DECLARE  v_cnt INT; 

BEGIN
    select count(*) into v_cnt 
    from user_tab_columns 
    where upper(table_name) = upper('myTable') and upper(column_name) = upper('template');

    IF(v_cnt = 0) THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE MYTABLE ADD TEMPLATE NVARCHAR2(255)';

        UPDATE MYTABLE 
        SET TEMPLATE = 'BASE VALUE';
    END IF; 
  END; /
```

The error that I'm getting is

> ORA-06550: line 10, column 37:
>   `PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "TEMPLATE": invalid identifier`

When trying to run these statements manually, everything seems to be working fine. I believe the issue is related to the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` portion, with which I'm not familiar. After preliminary Googling I can't determine that this statement is asynchronous or anything like that, so in theory there should be no error thrown there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution, shortly after posting the question. It is actually a compilation issue. The Oracle compiler reads the entire script before execution and throws an exception because I'm trying to explicitly update a column that, at the time immediately before the script running, does not exist.

The solution was to put the `UPDATE` statements in `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` blocks.

```
....
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE EGPL_USER_ROLE SET TEMPLATE = ''BASE VALUE''';
....
```

Answer (score 0):

The column name you are attempting to add, TEMPLATE, is a reserved word. See ORA-00904 and see the reserved word list (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10530_01/doc/epm.931/html_esb_techref/maxl/ddl/keywords.htm).

Change the name to 'A_TEMPLATE' and it will execute.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the case. I've made the changes as I noted below and everything is working fine.

Comment: Yes, I commented out the line, UPDATE MYTABLE SET TEMPLATE = 'BASE VALUE';, when I made my change. I agree with your solution.

Comment: That list of keywords is for Hyperion, not the RDBMS. `TEMPLATE` isn't in [the 11gR2 list](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e10830/appb.htm). (Makes a change from someone linking to MySQL docs though *8-).